How does Dereferencing with Traits and Trait functions with Slices and Arrays work
(I am new to rust and trying to write a little card game as an exercise and I might not have grasped some things correctly. I am trying to break down my problem/confusion as much as I can.)
I want to shuffle a vector randomly. For that I use the shuffle function from the rand crate.
Due to a problem I got because of another implementation for shuffle and wanting to call it via trait name, I stumpled upon some interesting but confusing stuff: shuffle is implemented by the SliceRandom trait which applies to [T] (slices of type T), it is not implemented for Vec<T> but the Deref trait is implemented for Vec<T> which acts as a bridge by coercing Vec<T> into &[T], which is also stated here.
fn main() {
    let mut vector_deck: Vec<u32> = (1..=24).collect::<Vec<u32>>();
    vector_deck.shuffle(&mut thread_rng());                    // 1 works
    SliceRandom::shuffle(&mut vector_deck, &mut thread_rng()); // 2 doesn't work

    let mut slice_deck: &mut [u32] = vector_deck.deref_mut();
    slice_deck.shuffle(&mut thread_rng());                     // 3 works
    SliceRandom::shuffle(slice_deck, &mut thread_rng());       // 4 works

    let mut array_deck: [u32; 24] = vector_deck.try_into().unwrap();
    array_deck.shuffle(&mut thread_rng());                     // 5 works
    SliceRandom::shuffle(&mut array_deck, &mut thread_rng());  // 6 doesn't work
}

This results in
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<u32>: SliceRandom` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:36:26
   |
36 |     SliceRandom::shuffle(&mut vector_deck, &mut thread_rng()); // 2 doesn't work
   |     -------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `SliceRandom` is not implemented for `Vec<u32>`
   |     |
   |     required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `SliceRandom` is implemented for `[T]`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u32; 24]: SliceRandom` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:44:26
   |
44 |     SliceRandom::shuffle(&mut array_deck, &mut thread_rng()); // 6 doesn't work
   |     -------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `SliceRandom` is not implemented for `[u32; 24]`
   |     |
   |     required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `SliceRandom` is implemented for `[T]`

And here is the confusion:

works because of the coercion I mentioned before,
does not work, which I don't understand because to my understanding it should work just like 1, by dereferencing on its own into a &[u32], but it results in error, so I dereferenced myself and
works just like 1,
works as I expected 2 to work which makes it more confusing,
works for the same reason as 1 does,
does again not work, although I somewhat expected this to work for an array but since an array itself is not a slice it is exactly the same problem as in 2?

So how does the dereferencing exactly work and how would I use SliceRandom::shuffle(&mut array_deck, &mut thread_rng()) on an array since there exists no 'workaround' (deref_mut()) for it?

The coercion in 1) works, because on the method call the compiler knows that it can coerce a mutable Vec<T> into a &mut [T]. Otoh when you pass &mut vector_deck to the trait method directly, you don't give the compiler an option. You explicitly request the passed value to be &mut Vec<T> which is not &mut [T]. You need to explicitly pass a valid type that implements the trait in this case. E.g. try passing vector_deck.as_mut_slice().

Mutable deref coercion is generally able to turn a &mut T into a &mut U whenever T: DerefMut<Target = U>. Normally a function call with a fixed type will perform the mutable deref coercion on its own, but in this case the issue is that SliceRandom::shuffle is a trait function taking &mut self, and so the type of the argument isn't actually known — it's &mut Self for some Self implementing SliceRandom, and Rust won't generally reason that there is only a single eligible type that satisfies a trait (i.e., that &mut Vec<T> only mutably derefs into &mut [T], and [T] implements SliceRandom) — which means there is no clear target type for DerefMut. If a function explicitly takes a &mut U for some fixed U, then you can pass a &mut T to it whenever T: DerefMut<Target = U>.
